# How to use callbacks on methods with certain naming patterns?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I am trying to find a beautiful way of declaring callbacks on methods with certain name patterns.
For example:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_venue, only: [:get_location, :get_date, :get_time, :sort_teams, :get_teams]
end
```

`except` or `only` there are a lot of methods to declare either way.

How can I perform something like `before_action: only:[:get_*, :sort_teams_by_*]`

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a callable (proc or a lambda) as the `if:` option:

```
before_action :set_venue, 
  if: proc { |c| c.action_name =~ /^(get|sort_teams_by)_*/ }
```

But this seems like a *clever* solution to legitimize some really smelly code. The names of all those actions in your controller are a dead give-away that you have some very un-RESTful routes like `users/1/get_location` instead of `users/1/location` and `users/1/teams`.

It also tells us that that controller 'may have way to many responsibilities and is handling multiple different resources. For example `users/1/get_teams` really should be `users/1/teams` and be handled by `Users::TeamsController`.

See:

- [Nested resources](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources)
- [Filters](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters)

Comment: Swear to God, I came back to write same answer using proc and conditions.
But I have one question: does it hinder performance ?

Comment: No I can't really imagine that it will have any performance impact. Still is stinky as hell though. Whenever you're prefacting anything with `get_` or `set_` in Ruby your spidey sense should be through the roof.

Comment: It is not handling different recources it is a controller for telegram-bot that handle single post. It was suggested by gem owner to write it that way.
Source code here: https://github.com/Nmerey/team_sorter_bot/blob/master/app/controllers/telegram_webhooks_controller.rb
Please feel free to advice me how I can make it more RESTful. Any help appreciated.

Comment: If you have to match an existing API thats one thing but your internal code layout definitly does not need to suffer from it and that code has got way to much logic for a controller. And is going to be hard to test. Brandon Keepers formulated a pretty good litmus test for classes - if you can't write the top level class description without using the words "and" or "or" you have to much going on.

Comment: Did not understand anything at all. Can you please elaborate on your words using some example from the source code ?